# git rebase resulted in a mess - how do I fix this?

Tags: git, rebase

I messed up my git repo by trying to simplify ("linearize") it with an interactive rebase / squash, but accidentally introduced a merge path.

Currently, it looks like this:

```
*  AAAAAAA (origin/master, master)
|\  
| * BBBBBBB ....
* | CCCCCCC (HEAD) .....
|/  
* DDDDDDD .....
* EEEEEEE .....

etc...
```

What I now would like to achieve is the structure below (there is nothing important in AAAAAAA and BBBBBBB, they are "garbage" resulting from my branch & rebase attempt):

```
* CCCCCCC (HEAD, origin/master, master)  
* DDDDDDD .....
* EEEEEEE .....
```

BTW, I am the only one using the remote repo, so there is no problem changing its structure (I am aware of the problems this could cause otherwise, but this is not the issue of my post).

Thanks for your help

Comment: from the `master` branch use `git reset --hard CCCCCC`, as a start

Comment: This finally worked:

Comment: This finally worked: I used git reset --hard CCCC, then checked out BBBB, then rebased CCCC, and finally used 'push -f origin master'.

Answer (score 0):

Using `git rebase -i` you can still achieve this with an association of pick and stash.

You can try to squash *AAAAAAA* and *BBBBBBB* and pick *CCCCCC*, *DDDDDD* and *EEEEEE*.

Garbage will then be put into *CCCCCC*.

Comment: this seems interesting, can you ellaborate more?

Comment: When using rebase in interactive mode, every changes inside of "squashed" commits will have to be put somewhere else by git. This "somewhere else" is the next picked commit you will select. Then git will merge your changes from all squashed commits inside the picked one. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I fear I missed something. When I try this, I can get to a new HEAD (which I could also do with a simple checkout of CCCCCCC, but master and origin/master stays where it is).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply want to get rid of AAA and BBB. As long as `master` as shown in your diagram is the latest tip of the branch and there are no newer commits, it is as simple as `git branch -f` or `git reset --hard`.

**NOTE**: make sure you do not have any uncommitted changes, since `git reset --hard` will remove them *for good*.

#### Approach 1: reset

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard CCC
```

#### Approach 2: branch

This will only work if `master` is not currently checked out. If it is, use approach 1 or detach HEAD, then check out master again.

```
git branch -f master CCC
```

#### Final step: sync with remote

Once your history is intact again, you must force-push it to your remote. A normal "fast-forward" push is not possible, because you have changed your local history. Git will refuse and suggest you to run pull or merge. That is not the right thing to do here. Instead:

```
git push origin +master
```